# Cannot remove line when blank

Tags: jasper-reports

I have checked **Remove Line When Blank** and set **Print When Expression** `$F{item} !=null`.
But the row cannot remove when the data is null.
[image]

The code is quite long, I can provide the design layout first,
If you want i can send you my jrxml file, thanks~
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I remember I did not have this problem before, but somehow it appear.

The option **Remove Line When Blank** should be remove field when field data is blank or null, but it didn't works.

Then I search on Google, finally solved the problem:

> the option only operates when the field2 don't touch field3.
>
> Maybe you should set positiontype on Float...
>
> naturally it works...:cheer:
>
> From link: [Remove Line When Blank?](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/515192/remove-line-when-blank)

It's because I have adjusted the positions of fields.

The field that I checked **Remove Line When Blank** option is touch another field, so it don't works.

when I drag the field in the iReport software make sure they don't touch each other, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You must be receiving **empty strings** (i.e. of length zero) instead of proper field values or `null`. The empty string also passes your *print when* check since `"" != null` is true.

You either have to:

1. Alter you *print when* expression to account for empty strings or
2. Convert incoming empty strings to `null` in the field expression like so

   `$F{field_name} == null ? null : $F{field_name}.isEmpty() ? null : $F{field_name}`